# TSQL Query - Need to single out rows that are not duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have over 3000 rows of duplicate data and I basically need to delete the duplicate data where `Env_ID ='1'` but I firstly need to check whether there are some data rows with `Env_id = '1'` that are not duplicates compared to `Env_ID ='4'`

Is this clear? Can anyone please assist?

Comment: so basically this is the code (not entirely accurate) select * from [Core_IBE].[dbo].[CR_ITEM] where Env_ID = '1' BUT IS NOT '4'

Comment: This isn't very clear can you please post some table structure, sample data, and what your expected duplicate in the sample data is.

Comment: @user3983253 can you take a look into http://sqlfiddle.com/ and add that to your question?

Comment: sorry --  this would be (Item_Number)

Comment: So within table (CR_ITEM) I have 7300 rows, 3434 have Env_id = '1' and 3867 have Env_ID ='4'. I want to safely remove the Env ID = '1' data but I needed to firstly check whether there are any rows containing ENV ID ='1' that are not duplicates of ENV_ID = '4'. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: That's about the same you said in the question.. Still not making it very clear though. Try to add some example data. Are you trying to delete rows that have `Env_id=1` but not also `Env_id=4`?

Comment: Is there a primary key on the table?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are saying that there might be two rows one with Env_id=1 and another with Env_id=4 BUT the rest of the fields of the table might be exactly the same? That's what makes them duplicate? In order to help you at least put the schema of your table.

Comment: I'll try again, sorry. So Basically the env_id = '1' is the old environment and env_id = '4' is the new environment. So when the data got mirrored across to the data warehouse all the env_id = '1' data stayed in there. Before I delete it out of the table I needed to check whether there were any rows containing env_id = '1' that are not only duplicates

Comment: @user3983253 instead of describing what the problem is why can't you edit your question to contain, the table structure. This would be a lot more clear than explaining with words. Just post the table structure, some sample data and what the duplicates are in the sample data.

Comment: Source_ID Env_ID Record_ID Item_Number Item_Description Item_Class
1 1 IM 0010000500K2#TI BOLA B.1.6".5-1AC              KA
1 4 IM 0010000500K2#TI BOLA B.1.6".5-1AC              KA

Comment: How about the complete schema? Constraints? At least PK?

Comment: I strongly suggest looking at some of the other "duplicate rows in a table" questions on this site. Your question is likely already answered. Here is a good one to start you off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Comment: 6 columns all with duplicate data, the only difference is the env_id. I need to check there are no ROWS containing env_id = '1' that AREN'T DUPLICATES.

Comment: Source_id, Env_ID and Item_Number are all PK. There are no constraints

Comment: @user3983253 There are loads of people here trying to help you, and asking for more information so they can help. How about you giving us the information we need to help you? "Source_ID Env_ID Record_ID Item_Number Item_Description Item_Class 1 1 IM 0010000500K2#TI BOLA B.1.6".5-1AC KA 1 4 IM 0010000500K2#TI BOLA B.1.6".5-1AC KA" is absolutely meaningless to us. Edit your question, give us a table structure and some sample data and we will help, otherwise we can't.

Comment: Ok, the column names in my table are Source_ID, ENV_ID, Record_ID, Item_Number, Item_Description, Item Class. The sample data from these columns is (in order) (1,1,IM,0010000500K2#TI,BOLA B.1.6".5-1AC,KA). This example of data is historic data and needs removing from the database, there are over 3000 rows with ENV_ID = '1', all of these need deleting because they are from an old environment. The new environment has populated data into the database that has created duplicates of the historic data, the only difference is the ENV_ID (environment id) which is now 4 (tbc)...

Comment: So the duplicate rows are the same (with the execption of the ENV_ID '4'). I know there are over 3000 rows with ENV_ID '1' and over 3000 rows with ENV_ID '4' that contain all same data. Before I delete the ENV_ID '1' rows I wanted to check if there are any more rows in the database containing ENV_ID '1' that are not duplicated by ENV_ID '4' rows. Please tell me this makes sense, I dont know how else to explain lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it goes:

Schema:

```
create table TableName 
( Source_ID varchar(100) not null,
 Env_ID varchar(100) not null,
 Record_ID  varchar(100),
 Item_Number varchar(100) not null, 
 Item_Description varchar(100), 
 Item_Class varchar(100)
)
alter table TableName add constraint PK_Env primary key (Env_ID, Source_ID, Item_Number)

insert into TableName (Source_ID,
                   Env_ID, 
                   Record_ID, 
                   Item_Number, 
                   Item_Description,
                   Item_Class)
values ('1','1','IM','0010000500K2#TI', 'BOLA B.1.6".5-1AC','KA')

insert into TableName (Source_ID,
                   Env_ID, 
                   Record_ID, 
                   Item_Number, 
                   Item_Description,
                   Item_Class)
values ('1','4','IM','0010000500K2#TI', 'BOLA B.1.6".5-1AC','KA')
```

Solution from: [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

```
;WITH cte
 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Source_ID, Record_ID, Item_Number, Item_Description, Item_Class
                                   ORDER BY (Env_ID) desc) RN
     FROM   TableName WHERE Env_ID = '1' or Env_ID = '4')
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1
```

It checks all fields BUT Env_ID. Hope it helps and next time please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thankyou sir, this sorted the issue. Sorry for the confusion earlier with my previous comments #newb

Comment: @user3983253 Next time you should do more research, there was already an answer to your problem and know I'm getting downvoted for helping you.

Comment: Well done, +1 for the considerable effort